# Refresh the DataTable plugin table in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, datatables

I used the Data Tables.

DataTables is a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library.

I upload a set of files.that upload files are stored in a array.

I displayed that array value using in table format using the DataTables plugin. Then I delete some upload files. So now I have updated array. Now I want to refresh the Table and display the new array in the table format. Is there any option to refresh the table in the dataTable plugin or any other way is available or not.

Comment: Could you provide a source code with a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Re-Initialization is the solution what you can have as alternate for your kind of functionality,i.e.,

For every update of your files and array clear() existing data, and destroy() dataTable and Initialize it with updated array dataset.

```
     var table = $('#example').DataTable();
```

after updation of array

lets assume variable "updatedArray" is having updated values.then call

```
table.clear();
table.destroy();
```

now initialize

```
 table = $('#example').DataTable({
  "data": updatedArray,
  "columns": columnArray
 });
```